# Create Eclipse Menu Option for PropertyPage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating an Eclipse `PropertyPage` and I would like the property to be accessed by right clicking the project and clicking on the menu option and sub menu option that I provide.

An example:

Right click a project *Build Path* -> *Configure Build Path...*
This opens up a property.

So far I have tried the following:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
     <menu
           icon="myIcon.png"
           label="Continuous Integration">
        <command
              commandId="myCommandID"
              icon="myIcon.png"
              label="Configure CI..."
              style="push">
        </command>
     </menu>
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
  </menuContribution>
```

This will create the menu options that I want but I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: path.to.class.ContinuousIntegration cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler
```

Comment: The error is in your command handler which must implement `IHandler` (usually by extending `AbstractHandler`)

Comment: Okay, but is this the correct approach to creating the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I would set the locationURI to only show up in the ProjectExplorer such as this:

```
<menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
```

And make sure the handler and command are set like [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/eclipse-rcp-tutorial-add-a-menu-item-to-the-popup-menu-when-right-click-a-file/)